# Need help in building MYSQL query to count two content from single row/table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get count of two set of data which is listed under same table name, with specific date range.

Table 'Event'

```
u_id event  Create
123  F_log  25-Sep-16
127  C_log  25-Sep-16
123  F_log  25-Sep-16
126  F_log  25-Sep-16
185  M_log  25-Sep-16
146  D_log  25-Sep-16
173  F_log  26-Sep-16
183  C_log  26-Sep-16
193  F_log  26-Sep-16
204  M_log  27-Sep-16
214  D_log  27-Sep-16
225  F_log  27-Sep-16
```

**Expected result**

```
Created    F_log    C_log
25-Sep-16   2       1
26-Sep-16   2       1
```

My query which is not giving correct result;

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT e.user_id) AS Flash,
         COUNT (DISTINCT et.user_id) AS Client,
         TO_CHAR (e.created) AS Date_created
    FROM events e INNER JOIN events et ON e.user_id = et.user_id
   WHERE     e.created BETWEEN '25-SEP-15' AND '27-SEP-15'
         AND e.event_type = 'Flash C log'
         AND et.event_type = 'Client C log'
GROUP BY TO_CHAR (e.created);
```

Comment: table data looks messy when I copy pasted. Please refer to the image. http://imgur.com/a/sZ2dg

Comment: tried "select count(distinct e.event_type), count(distinct et.event_type) 
from events e inner join events et on e.user_id=et.user_id 
where e.event_type='Flash C log' and et.event_type='Client C log'
and e.created between '25-SEP-16' and '26-SEP-16';"

Comment: How do you apply a date range to this? MySQL has no understanding of what an '26-SEP-16' is.

Comment: in some of my query i've used to_char(s.created, 'YYYY-MM-DD') and it worked. In this case I am really confused. I know it is simple but not sure what I have missed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Building mysql query to count specific data under same table/row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39699759/building-mysql-query-to-count-specific-data-under-same-table-row)

Comment: @Linkan thx for pointing out the self-dupe re-ask by op

Comment: That said the one you answered was asked 2 to 3 hours later

Comment: @Drew Didn't see this question yesterday.

Comment: @Linkan I combined the questions and closed the other way back to the orig. Please add your answer here.

Comment: @PraveenYadhav don't dupe up and re-ask a question hours later. It litters the site and that is not the way we roll here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select to_char(cast(created as date),'YYYY-MM-DD') as Report_date,
count(distinct(case when event_type in ('Flash C Log') then user_id else 0 end)) as Flash_Log,
count(distinct(case when (event_type = 'Client C Log') then user_id else 0 end)) as Client_Log
from events e
where created between '25-SEP-16' and '27-SEP-16'
group by to_char(cast(created as date),'YYYY-MM-DD')
order by to_char(cast(created as date),'YYYY-MM-DD');

Answer (score 0):

**Query**

```
SELECT t.`Create`, 
SUM(CASE WHEN t.`F_log` > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as `F_log`,
SUM(CASE WHEN t.`C_log` > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as `C_log` FROM(
    select `u_id`, `Create`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `event` = 'F_log' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `F_log`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `event` = 'C_log' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `C_log`
    FROM `Event`
    GROUP BY `u_id`, `Create`
)t
GROUP BY t.`Create`;
```

Comment: Hi Ullas, Thanks for replying . I tried your query but It gave me some error. I modulated few data before posting. may be I am doing some thing wrong when trying to apply your query.

Comment: I have posted below my actual data if this will help

Comment: Table "events"  
user_id event_type Created
123 Flash C log 25-Sep-16
127 Client C log 25-Sep-16
123 Flash C log 25-Sep-16
126 Flash C log 25-Sep-16
185 Monitor log 25-Sep-16
146 Delete log 25-Sep-16
173 Flash C log 26-Sep-16
183 Client C log 26-Sep-16
193 Flash C log 26-Sep-16
204 Monitor log 27-Sep-16
214 Delete log 27-Sep-16
225 Flash C log 27-Sep-16

Comment: Any help on this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The COUNTs has to be done in separate subqueries. This should work.

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.created,F.flash,C.client
FROM events E
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT created,COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) as flash
    FROM events
    WHERE event_type LIKE 'Flash C log'
    GROUP BY created
) F
ON F.created = E.created
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Created,COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) as client
    FROM events
    WHERE event_type LIKE 'Client C log'
    GROUP BY created
) C
ON C.created = E.created
WHERE E.created BETWEEN '2016-09-25' AND '2016-09-27'
```

[Fiddle with results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/be4493/1)

EDIT: As of your comments, I have made a question that adds a column of the distinct combined userids with clients and flash logs for each date. I added a little data to that fiddle to test.

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.created,F.flash,C.client,FC.combined
FROM events E
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT created,COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) as flash
    FROM events
    WHERE event_type LIKE 'Flash C log'
    GROUP BY created
) F
ON F.created = E.created
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Created,COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) as client
    FROM events
    WHERE event_type LIKE 'Client C log'
    GROUP BY created
) C
ON C.created = E.created
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Created,COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) as combined
    FROM events
    WHERE event_type LIKE 'Client C log' OR event_type LIKE 'Flash C log'
    GROUP BY created
) FC
ON FC.created = E.created
WHERE E.created BETWEEN '2016-09-25' AND '2016-09-27'
```

[SQL Fiddle for answer 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/790ec2/1)