# Building mysql query to count specific data under same table/row

Tags: mysql, sql

```
 
Table name "events"
```

```
   
 user_id    event_type      Created
    123     Flash C log     25-Sep-16
    127     Client C log    25-Sep-16
    123     Flash C log     25-Sep-16
    126     Flash C log     25-Sep-16
    185     Monitor log     25-Sep-16
    146     Delete log      25-Sep-16
    173     Flash C log     26-Sep-16
    183     Client C log    26-Sep-16
    193     Flash C log     26-Sep-16
    204     Monitor log     27-Sep-16
    214     Delete log      27-Sep-16
    225     Flash C log     27-Sep-16
```

**Expect result**

```
Date       Flash C log   Client C log 
25-Sep-16      2               1 
26-Sep-16      2               1 
27-Sep-16      1               0
```

My query which is not giving correct result;

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT e.user_id) AS Flash,
         COUNT (DISTINCT et.user_id) AS Client,
         TO_CHAR (e.created) AS Date_created
    FROM events e INNER JOIN events et ON e.user_id = et.user_id
   WHERE     e.created BETWEEN '25-SEP-15' AND '27-SEP-15'
         AND e.event_type = 'Flash C log'
         AND et.event_type = 'Client C log'
GROUP BY TO_CHAR (e.created);
```

Comment: select count(distinct e.user_id) as Flash, count(distinct et.user_id) 
as Client, to_char(e.created) as Date_created 
from events e inner join events et on e.user_id=et.user_id 
where e.created between '25-SEP-15' 
and '27-SEP-15' and e.event_type='Flash C log' 
and et.event_type='Client C log' 
group by to_char(e.created);

Comment: I combined your questions. Don't re-ask a question hours later. It litters the site.

Answer (score 0):

The COUNTs has to be done in separate subqueries. This should work.

EDIT: Corrected a couple of stupid mistakes and included a fiddle with the answer.

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.created,F.flash,C.client
FROM events E
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT created,COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) as flash
    FROM events
    WHERE event_type LIKE 'Flash C log'
    GROUP BY created
) F
ON F.created = E.created
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Created,COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) as client
    FROM events
    WHERE event_type LIKE 'Client C log'
    GROUP BY created
) C
ON C.created = E.created
WHERE E.created BETWEEN '2016-09-25' AND '2016-09-27'
```

[Fiddle with results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/be4493/1)

Comment: Hi Linkan, I tried your query and it returned me with error.  "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 5 Column: 22"

Comment: SELECT to_char(E.created),F.flash_log, C.client_log
FROM events E
left join
(SELECT created,COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) as flash_log
from events where event_type = 'Flash C log' GROUP BY created) F
ON F.created = E.created
left join
(SELECT Created,COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) as client_log
from events  where  event_type = 'Client C log'
GROUP BY created) C
ON C.created = E.created
WHERE to_char(E.created) BETWEEN '25-SEP-15' AND '27-SEP-15';

Comment: Above query is fetching the details but its not grouping :( so close

Comment: @PraveenYadhav I have corrected some mistakes in my code. Try it out again.

Comment: @Linkan please add your answer to the orig question over there. Thx

Comment: @Linkan I have used below query this is fetching me data as I need, but the count of user_id is not distinct.

Comment: SELECT  to_char(E.created) as DATE_LOG, count(F.flash_log) as FLASH_LOG, count(C.client_log) as CLIENT_LOG
FROM events E
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT created,COUNT( distinct user_id) as flash_log
    FROM events
    WHERE event_type= 'Flash C log'
    GROUP BY created 
) F
ON F.created = E.created
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT created,COUNT(distinct user_id) as client_log
    FROM events
    WHERE event_type = 'Client C log'
    GROUP BY created 
) C
ON C.created = E.created
WHERE E.created BETWEEN '13-JAN-16' AND '16-JAN-16'
group by to_char(e.created)

Comment: @PraveenYadhav I have tested this, and for me the count is distinct. Can you explain in what way it isn't distinct to you? And please, answer in your first (still open) question.

Comment: SO, let me explain this in details.  I usually use two different query to fetch data. I have listed below the two query which I use separately.

1
SELECT to_char(created),count(distinct user_id) as Flash_log from events where event_type = 'Flash C Log' 
and created between '13-JAN-16' AND '16-JAN-16' group by to_char(created) order by to_char(created) asc

2
SELECT to_char(created), count(distinct user_id) as Client_log from events where event_type = 'Client C Log' 
and created between '13-JAN-16' AND '16-JAN-16' group by to_char(created) order by to_char(created) asc

Comment: Since the created(date) is common on both of this query, I wanted to fetch distinct count of "Flash C log" and "Client C log". when I run your query on my DB it is actually fetching total count of "Flash C Log" and "Client C log" on the specified date. I dont know If I am being such a bug but I am working towards this from past 2 or 3 days

Comment: @PraveenYadhav After your comments I edited this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39696470/need-help-in-building-mysql-query-to-count-two-content-from-single-row-table/39730376#39730376 comments there please.

Comment: @Linkan Thanks for all your help. I figured out the exact query which fetches my results. I have updated this on this thread.

Comment: @PraveenYadhav Please vote on answers that has helped you (and possibly accept them as well).